# Problem with session

Tags: sessions

I am working in Drupal and Magento Integration

Whenever i try to get session data using this code

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mage1/app/Mage.php";
  umask(0);
  Mage::app("default");

  $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

  if ($session->isLoggedIn()) {
    $block['content'] .= $session->getCustomer()->getName();
    #var_dump($session->getData());
  }
  else {
    $block['content'] = t('User not logged in');
  }
```

it fails to fetch the data.

But when i run this from independent php code it works fine.

But magento's catalog objects are running perfectly inside Drupal

What could be the problem. Any suggestions

Am using D7

EDIT

```
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/mage1/app/Mage.php";
      umask(0);
      Mage::app();
      Mage::app()->getTranslator()->init('frontend');
      Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));

      // switch off error reporting
      error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);

      // Brands category => ID = 101
      $brand = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load('4');
      $brands = $brand->getChildrenCategories();

      foreach ($brands as $node) {
        $items[] = array(
            'data' => t($node['name'])
        );
      }

      $block['content'] .= theme('item_list', array(
          'items' => $items
              ));
```

This is the code i use to get the catalog products from magento and display in drupal
I don't use any package for that.This is working perfectly.

Comment: where are you putting this code? in any hook of your custom module? are you sure your code is being called?

Comment: am putting this inside hook_block_view

Comment: Hi zamil, [cross-site posting of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196351/session-handling-in-drupal) is not allowed. Would you rather this one was closed or the one on Stack Overflow?

Comment: ok i will close it here.how to do that

Comment: i dont know what is happening. one person delted my post from stackoverflow. i told you to delete it from here, there i was getting some answers. its sad :)

Comment: I'm only a mod over here, not on Stack Overflow - I didn't close that post, but since it's deleted this one can stay open

Comment: Are you using a module to get the Magento catalog objects into Drupal, or are you doing that yourself in a method similar to above? I would guess that it has to do with how Drupal handle's the session itself (`session_set_save_handler()`, etc) and the Magento module includes code to marry the two. Just a guess – give us more info and I'll try to help.

Comment: The only answer over there was "Check the cookie path settings under System > Configuration > Web." (I am not a Stack Overflow moderator, but I asked to SO moderators.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588483/magento-and-drupal-sessions-conflicts-how-to-resolve is a similar thread. as per this what is the equivalent of destroyTemporaryJoomlaSession and restartJoomlaSession in Drupal 7

Comment: @CharlieS: i have edited my question to add the code i use to fetch the catalog products from magento

Comment: Gotcha, so the code for displaying products doesn't depend on the session in any way. When you run the code, I assume you see "$block['content'] = t('User not logged in');"? Is that what you mean by "it fails to fetch the data"?

Comment: @CharlieS: yes, if session is present it should show the logged in user name with this $session->getCustomer()->getName(); or at least it should not show _User not logged in_

Comment: The methods that are tied with session object is not fetching any data when i am already logged into magento as a customer

Comment: When you bootstrap Drupal you change the session handlers to use Drupal's database's `session` table. Check out this module and search for others like it, OR you'll have to write a method for Magenta to use Drupal's session handler or vice versa: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/drupal.html

Comment: @CharlieS: this module is for D6 and Magento 1.6 which are previous versions of both open sources.

Comment: You might want to post here for more help: http://groups.drupal.org/magento. To solve your problem it's going to require someone with understanding of how Magento handles sessions and marrying that to Drupal. Both of these systems are storing sessions in different places.

Comment: @CharlieS :Thanks let me move to the space you suggested :)

Comment: Surprising they deleted your question on SO -- I've posted Magento/Drupal integrations there previously with a fairly high degree of success. Regardless, it's totally a session issue. There's a namespace conflict with how Magento and Drupal handle sessions -- you ultimately need to save Drupal's stuff into a variable, destroy that session, create Magento's session, do stuff, destroy Magento's session, recreate Drupal's.